# A question on hyperelliptic curves and units

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $P(t) \in k[t]$ be a separable polynomial of even degree $\geq 2$ over an algebraically closed field k with $char(k) \neq 2$. Let us consider the hyperelliptic curve X over k defined by $y^2= P(t)$. Show that the following are equivalent:

(1) There exists $A,B \in k[t]$ s.t $A^2-P(t)B^2=1$.

(2) $k[t,y]* \neq k$

(3) Let $x_1,x_2$ be the points of the support of $(t)_\infty$ . Then the divisor $x_1-x_2 \in Pic^0(X)$ is an element of finite order.

I have no problem with showing that $(1) \implies (2)$ or $(2) \iff (3)$, but I can't seem to figure out anything about 1 and 3... Could anyone give me a hint here? I assume that $A+By$ has the required divisors , but I have no idea how to show this.

Comment: For (3) implies (1): let $f$ be a rational function whose divisor is $n(x_1-x_2)$, where $n$ is the order of $x_1-x_2$ in $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$. Then $f$ is regular without zero (hence invertible) on $X \setminus \{ x_1, x_2\}$. This means that $f\in O_X(X\setminus \{x_1, x_2\})^*=(k[t, y])^*$. Write $f=A(t)+yB(t)$. Then the norm of $f$ in $k[t]$ is also invertible. Now this norm is $A^2-P(t)B^2$...

Comment: Why must the norm be invertible?

Comment: Dear @Tedar, this is quite standard. What should be the inverse of the norm ?

Comment: @Cantlog I am probably missing something obvious now, but say we have $f=A(t)+yB(t)$ , so the norm is $A^2-P(t)B^2$. Now, $A+yB$ has an inverse - but don't this require one for $A-yB$?

Comment: $A-yB$ is the conjugate of $A+yB$, so it is also invertible. Anyway, if $g$ is the inverse of $f$, the relation $fg=1$ implies $N(f)N(g)=1$. So $N(f)$ is invertible in $k[t]$. Therefore $N(f)=\lambda=\mu^2\in k^*$. This implies that $(A/\mu)^2-P(B/\mu)^2=1$.

Comment: @Cantlog Turned out I am not sure about (2) -> (3) either, do you have any hint here?

Comment: I.e what I am afraidof - what if my unit doesn't have zerosand poles at the prescribed points?

Comment: @Cantlog OK, think I got it. That $k[t,y]^\ast \neq k$, implies that there is an unit in the open $O_X(X_\{x_1,x_2\})$. Now, a divisor must have sum of zeros and poles zero, thus it is asprescribed. Thanks!